# Show and Hide div element with pure CSS and HTML on click

Tags: html, css

I'd like to create a program where in:
* When you click Span 1, Span 2 will be displayed and Span 1 will be disabled.
* When you click Span 2, Span 1 will be displayed and Span 2 will be disabled.

This is my codes and I think it's strange. Your help is greatly appreciated.

CSS

```
body {
  display: block;
}
.span1:focus ~ .span2 {
  display: none;
}
.span2:focus ~ .span1 {
  display: block;
}
```

HTML

```
<span class="span1" tabindex="0">Span 1</span>
<span class="span2" tabindex="0">Span 2</span>
```

Comment: disabled or displayed?

Comment: correct code is `.span1:focus ~ .alert {
  display: none;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Use this css below:

```
body {
    display: block;
}
.span1:focus{
    color:gray;
}
.span2{
  color:gray;
}
.span1:focus ~ .span2 {
    display: inline-block;
    color:black;
}
.span2:focus{
    color:gray; 
}
.span2:focus ~ .span1 {
    color:black
}
```

Check the [jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sarowerj/ya9xmddw/)

Answer (score 0):

This problem can not be solved by Pure CSS and HTML , the answer can be found by javascript.

```
<span class="span1" tabindex="0" onclick="span1Clciked()">Span 1</span>
<span class="span2" tabindex="0" onclick="span2Clicked()">Span 2</span>
```

and on javascript

```
<script>
function span1Clicked(){
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("span2").item(0);
    x.style.visibility='hidden';
 // other stuff

}
function span2Clicked(){
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("span1").item(0);
    x.style.visibility='hidden';
 // other stuff

}    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be accomplished easily and with more flexibility in JavaScript. Example in jQuery:

```js
$('span').click(function() {
  $(this).css('visibility','hidden').siblings().css('visibility','visible');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="span1" tabindex="0">Span 1</span>
<span class="span2" tabindex="0">Span 2</span>
```